# no laser show in rviz2 and rqt

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i published a topic via "pointcloud_to_laserscan" node,

and i can view the data updated by **ros2 topic echo /scan**

but in RViz2 and rqt, the tools can see the topic, but no data updated?

how to fix the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361282/no-laser-show-in-rviz2-and-rqt/) by [chopin1998@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/57192/chopin1998@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i know the reason now...

the pub and sub has different reliability conf....

---

Originally posted by [chopin1998@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/57192/chopin1998@gmail.com/) with karma: 46 on 2020-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre123](https://answers.ros.org/users/102026/andre123/) on 2022-04-14**:
thanks dude works with my matlab problem, unable to see turtlebot3_,msgs/LaserScan data.
Had to change LaserScanSub = ros2subscriber(matlabNode, topicName); to LaserScanSub = ros2subscriber(matlabNode, topicName,"Reliability","besteffort");